# Using variables in environment names on Azure Devops Yml Pipeline

Tags: azure-devops

I have a pipeline with a deployment job that has a environment

environment: "myname-$(variable1)"

but when i look at environments in Azure Devops, it has not replaced the variable and named my environment "myname-$(variable1)" and not "myname-helloworld".

Any way to use varaibles for the environment names?

## Updated with example

```
stages.yml

stages:
- stage:
  variables:
    EnvironmentName: Prod
  jobs:
  - template: steps.yml
....

steps:yml

jobs:
- deployment: deployment

  environment: ${{ EnvironmentName }}
  strategy:
  ...
```

Answer (score 3):

The solution is to use parameters instead of variables.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops#insert-a-template

```
stages.yml

stages:
- stage:
  variables:
    EnvironmentName: Prod
  jobs:
  - template: steps.yml
    parameters:
      myParameter: Test
....

steps:yml
parameters:
- name: myParameter
jobs:
- deployment: deployment

  environment: ${{ parameters['myParameter']}}
  strategy:
  ...
```

Comment: You just moved the problem. The `myParameter` parameter still can not be a variable as the environment name is resolved before compile time.

Answer (score -1):

Refer to the [expressions documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops). You need to use a runtime or compile time expression.

`environment: "myname-${{ variable1 }}"`

That expands the variable value when the YAML file is parsed. If `variable` is a variable that you've defined, it will be expanded accordingly.

If `variable1` is defined at some point in the execution of the pipeline, then you need to use the runtime syntax: `$[ variable1 ]` instead.

Comment: Updated the question with example of ${{ }} that do not work.  Unrecognized value: 'EnvironmentName' located at position 1 within expression

Answer (score -1):

You can access the variable by using a compile time reference

```yaml
...
environment: ${{ variables['EnvironmentName']}}
```